# determine area of screen covered

Tags: c++, shader, directx-9

We have an app that allows a user to wipe away a top layer image using a "brush" attached to the mouse.  The brush can be any type of shape, such as a circle, star, W, or any random bizarre shape.

This is currently implemented in C++ using DirectX9 and shaders (3.0).  It is a legacy system and later versions of DirectX are not available.  A single channel opacity map accumulates the brush strokes.  The opacity map is then used as the alpha layer between the top and bottom images.

The problem is there is a requirement to auto-wipe the rest of the image when a certain percentage of the image has been revealed.  For example, if the user has already revealed 60% of the bottom layer, the app would automatically clear the rest of the opacity map to reveal all of it.  **The problem is trying to figure out how much of the opacity map has been wiped** without locking the surface and counting the pixels, as that is *really* slow.

Comment: Have you thought about injecting code between the brush strokes updating the opacity map and possibly keeping a (lower resolution) map in memory? ..... Another idea: the great thing about percentages is that you can still perform comparisons even if the resulting image is smaller.  I was thinking about mipmap generation, but you could potentially just render your opacity map to a smaller texture and checking the percentage on that.  Let the GPU do most of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

1. Create a 1x framebuffer
2. Create a shader that renders into this framebuffer by taking the sum of all opacity values for a column of pixels and writing it into that index in the  framebuffer. Each shader invocation should be responsible for a single column of pixels.
3. Lock the framebuffer surface and sum up all of these pixel values. This should be a lot faster than doing it for the whole screen.
4. Compare your sum to the product of the original width and height.

Comment: Can you describe how you would get DirectX to sum up all of the columns?  If the opacity map is 1920x1080, wouldn't a single column's summation exceed the instruction count of the shader?  I say this because I ran into shader compilation errors of that sort when trying to loop over the texels of the opacity map.

Comment: I've actually never used DirectX; only OpenGL. I guess if you run into instruction limits, you can instead write to a framebuffer multiple pixels high, so each pixel in the output framebuffer is the sum of some fixed number of pixels in a column.

Comment: another solution might be to  use [GenerateMipMaps](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/GenerateMipMaps) to let the driver do this for you.

Comment: I got around the instruction limit issue by changing which shader function is used to sample the opacity map.  I had to use tex2Dlod() instead of tex2D().  It's not working 100% yet, but this method is looking very promising as both the draw call and the calls to access the pixels of the single row texture didn't make my frame rate drop to ridiculous values.  I can still get around 120fps.

Comment: If the final summation is still too slow, you could run a second shader to sum the row of pixels in the framebuffer instead of doing it on the CPU.